# How to enable 'Add Config Transforms' for old Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I am working in the new Visual Studio 2010 RTM and I would like to use web.config transforms.

My site is configured to use .NET 4.0 but it was formerly a Visual Studio 2008 web application project.

When I right-click on my web.config file I do not see the 'Add Config Transforms' option as I should.  I also tried adding creating a new web.config but I still do not see the transform option.

Does anyone know how to enable web.config transforms for projects in Visual Studio 2010 that were originally created in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Take a look at this post
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with my existing project.

I did it by opening my csproj file in notepad and comparing the  child elements to those of a brand new ASP.NET MVC project for VS2010.

I then removed several elements that I didn't need and saved and reloaded my project.  Then I was able to select 'Add Config Transforms.'

I do not know exactly which element was the culprit but I would guess it was either `<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>` or `<OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion</>`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work in my converted project by opening up the .proj file and adding the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Web.Staging.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then I copied my existing web.config twice into the web root and renamed them Web.Release.config and Web.Staging.config
In VS I right mouse clicked and included them in the project

I then opened them up and added

```
xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
```

to the configuration node so it looked like:

```
<configuration  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```

You have to have matching Release and Staging configuration names (using configuration manager).
After this VS recognised them as web configuration transformation files